# AccessType and RefreshToken in RequestToken call use case

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

In the REST API what is the purpose of the accessType and refreshToken parameters (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/requestToken.htm)

Are these for use on HubApps only? Would these be beneficial for a client adding Contacts through the API through their external processes?